# Subsets of properties in a Swagger definition

Tags: php, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-php

I'm writing an API where I have a Controller that POSTs a new object, GETs it back and can PUT/PATCH updates to it. The problem is that there's a difference in properties between the two different actions. For example, when I POST a new object I want to ensure that the 'id' of it is returned so that it can be used to identify it for the GET/PUT/PATCH endpoints. It doesn't matter if it comes back via the GET (it's just a duplication of data at that point) but I certainly don't want it passed for the PUT or PATCH as the id is immutable.

So what's the best way to mark this up in swagger so that I can have different versions of the same Definition? I've seen that you can use 'allOf' to add Definitions to other properties, but I'm wondering if there's a way of saying 'not these properties in the definition'?

If I could do the latter I could make one Definition of the object as a whole and simply knock out the things that aren't required to be returned or submitted when referencing it at the Controller. Is this possible? Am I making sense?

(Just to make things more interesting, my swagger.json file is being generated by swagger-php based on Annotations in my controller and entity files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am facing the same issue while writing our spec file, and didn't know how to fix it but what I used  is the property "readOnly":true, this way the documentation says that this is a readonly property, you can only read it through GET/POST methods but you cannot send it via PATCH/ PUT.. hope this helps